# A newbie question about operations with integers and floating-points in C

Tags: c

I'm a C language newbie. Just trying to figure out why one code example from the textbook "Absolute Beginner's Guide to C, 3rd Edition" works like that:

```
// Two sets of equivalent variables, with one set
// floating-point and the other integer

float a = 19.0;
float b = 5.0;
float floatAnswer;

int x = 19;
int y = 5;
int intAnswer;

// Using two float variables creates an answer of 3.8
floatAnswer = a / b;
printf("%.1f divided by %.1f equals %.1f\n", a, b, floatAnswer);

floatAnswer = x /y; //Take 2 creates an answer of 3.0
printf("%d divided by %d equals %.1f\n", x, y, floatAnswer);

// This will also be 3, as it truncates and doesn't round up
intAnswer = a / b;
printf("%.1f divided by %.1f equals %d\n", a, b, intAnswer);
```

The second output is not understandable to me. We take integers so why is there a floating-point "3.0"?

The third output is not clear too. Why is there 3 when we take floating-point numbers like 19.0 and 5.0?

Pls help

Comment: Dividing two integers results in an integer. It doesn't matter that you later turn that integer into a `float`

Comment: thank you I forgot about turning integers into a float

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the right-hand side (RHS) of the assignment is evaluated *first*: this is a division of *two integers*, so it is performed as such (an integer operation), and the result is `3`; this is then converted to a `float`, in order to fulfil the assignment, and the conversion from an *integral* `3` cannot have any fractional part. However, the left-hand side is a `float` and, in the `printf` format, you are *explicitly* asking for 1 decimal place in the output - even though that is (and must be) zero.

In the third example, the RHS is evaluated as a floating-point division, which will (as you suspect) give an *interim* value of 3.8; however, when this is then converted to an `int`, in order to fulfil the assignmment, the fractional part (`.8`) is lost, as an integer cannot have any fractional component. Conversion from a floating-point type to an integer will *always* truncate (discard) any fractional part, so even converting `1.999999999` will give a value of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide `x/y` you get the integer `3` because it performs integer division. When you assign that to `floatAnswer`, the integer is automatically converted to the equivalent `float` value, which is `3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Second case.

In the second case you assign the result of the `int` operation to a `float`.

```
int a = 19;
int b = 5;
float floatAnswer = a/b;
```

In that last line you assign an `int` to a `float`, which is implicitely casted. But the division operation was done using integer arithmetic. The cast is the last step (when it is assigned).

So basically, that's equivalent to

```
float floatAnswer = 3;
```

which is doing the same as,

```
float floatAnswer = (float)3;
```

Note the (`float`). That means that the value 3 is being casted (converted) to `float`.

Third case.

In the third case you assign the result of `19.0/5.0` to an `int`,

```
float a = 19.0;
float b = 5.0;
int intAnswer = a/b;
```

This implicitly casts the value to an `int`, and casting `float` to int is being done by truncating.

In this case this would be equivalent to

```
int intAnswer = 3.8;
```

Which is doing the same as,

```
int intAnswer = (int)3.8;
```

the (`int`) means that the value is casted (converted) to an `int` type.

Comment: The question is about the second case, not the third case.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, OP is asking about 2nd **and** 3rd cases: *"The third output is not clear too."*

Comment: folks thank you all for help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can image as below:

```
floatAnswer = x /y;
```

From right to left, the program will calculate:

1. `temp = x/y`: because `x` and `y`; they are integer, so `temp = 3`.
2. `floatAnswer = temp`, now `temp = 3`, so `floatAnswer = 3`

```
intAnswer = a / b;
```

From right to left:

1. `temp = a/b` will be `3.8`
2. `intAnswer = temp`, but `intAnswer` is integer, so temp is cast to 3

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%.1f divided by %.1f equals %d\n", a, b, intAnswer);
```

`a/b` becomes `19.0/5.0` which is `3.8` and is reported that way.

Looking at the second case, we have:

```
floatanswer = x/y
floatanswer = 19/5
floatanswer = 3
printf( 3.0 )
```

You can see that the integers experience integer division **before** they are assigned to float answer.  That means the `printf` of float-answer isn't your problem, it's the integer division which happens before `floatanswer` is ever assigned the value.

Answer (score -1):

2nd case: As I see, you have defined floatanswer as a float variable, that why It is returning decimal value.

3rd case: Because You have defined intAnswer as integer, that's why it is returning interfere value